# SmtpClient to Hosted Exchange Server gives - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:25

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient, mailmessage

I've been banging my head against this one for weeks, but today was the day I promised I'd get it fixed. So far I've failed.

I am trying to send an email from a hosted MVC application, via a Hosted Exchange server. The IT department has said and confirmed that they have allowed the IP of the MVC application through. However, the following code gives me "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions ###.###.###.###:25" every time.

```
ActionResult Test()
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    message.From = new MailAddress("valid.email.address");
    message.Subject = "Test Email";
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("another.valid.email.address"));

    message.Body = "Hey, this is a test!";

    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        client.Port = 25;
        client.EnableSsl = true; // Either true or false gives same result
        client.Host = "actual.host.url";

        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.LogMessage = string.Format("Error: {0}<br />{1}<br />{2}", ex.Message, ex?.InnerException.Message, ex?.InnerException?.InnerException.Message);
            return View();
        }

        ViewBag.LogMessage = string.Format("client.Host: {0}<br />Client.Port: {1}<br />Client.EnableSsl: {2}<br />message.To[0].Address: {3}", client.Host, client.Port, client.EnableSsl ? "true" : "false", message.To[0].Address);
    }

    return View();
}
```

The value of the LogMessage is:

```
Error: Failure sending mail.
Unable to connect to the remote server
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions ###.###.###.###:25
```

Any suggestions would be welcome! I've tried port 587 with no luck. I've tried with and without credentials, with or without SSL, username matching from address or not. I've run out of things to try.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried any other ports besides '25'? By default port 25 is locked down pretty heavily depending on the version of exchange. I would try 465 and give it a shot. Its an undocumented SMTP port for exchange using STARTTLS. In my programs, I have to actually use port 587 to send anything out so give that a shot also

Comment: @KevinBBurns I've tried 25, 587, and 465 all with SSL enabled and disabled with no luck. The IT guy said 25 was used by other services that send mail, so I think it's on my end.

Comment: If you telnet to that port on that machine, are you receiving any data?

Comment: I am now assuming this development machine is on a domain, what anti-virus/ security suite does your place use? I know when I deployed Kaspersky I had to manually include SMTP traffic for development on my machine.

Comment: @KevinBBurns I actually get the same issue on my remote web server, which shouldn't have any ports blocked.

Comment: Well, I would try a telnet or netcat client and connect to a few different ports. If you get a response back then you at can rule out a firewall or port issue. Otherwise it will have to be something in the code at that point. Did you look at my code below, I am wondering if it has something to do with the issued SSL cert.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, the first line tells SMTP Client to ignore any issue with the SSL cert if its provide from an invalid provider.

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =(sender,certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("oba.exchangeserver.com")
        {
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            Credentials =
                new NetworkCredential("username","password")
        };
        return smtpClient;
```

Comment: When I use this code with my values I get "The SMTP host was not specified." I took the hose out of the declaration and added Host = "myhost" and got the same error.